# Mutex/lock construct raises MSVC warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mutex

In a library where multiple threads may need to access std::cout, I made the following function so that access to std::cout is controlled (with a very simple example how to use it...):

```
// Mutexed access to std::out.
inline void HelperFunctions::controlStdCoutAccess(const StdCoutAccess mode)
{
    static std::mutex m;
    static std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m, std::defer_lock);

    // Check if we lock or unlock.
    if (mode == StdCoutAccess::Lock)
        lock.lock();
    else
        lock.unlock();
}

// Print to std::cout, but mutexed for thread safety.
inline void HelperFunctions::mutexedPrint(const std::string& string)
{
    controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Lock);
    std::cout << string;
    controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Unlock);
}
```

In MSVC I get warnings: 'Failing to release lock', 'Failing to hold lock', 'Releasing unheld lock'. No warnings in gcc.

Is MVSC overlooking the possible usage of this construct, particularly mutex and lock being static? Or is the whole piece of code a bad idea and a better alternative exists? The warning just makes me wonder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) class like `std::unique_lock` static defeats the purpose of it. If you need explicit calls to lock/unlock, you might as well call `mutex.lock()` and `unlock()`. The unlocking should happen automatically when the `unique_lock` goes out of scope, e.g. after throwing an exception.

How about this instead:

```cpp
inline std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_cout()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
}
inline void HelperFunctions::mutexedPrint(const std::string& string)
{
    auto lock = lock_cout();
    std::cout << string;
}
```

If you have C++-20, you can use its synchronized IO routines instead:

```cpp
#include <syncstream>

inline void HelperFunctions::mutexedPrint(const std::string& string)
{
    std::osyncstream synced_out(std::cout);
    synced_out << string;
}
```

Comment: I dont think your 1. is correct. afaik `std::cout` is synchronized only on a per character level. Ie if one thread writes "aaa" the other writes "bbb" the output can be "ababa" or any combination.

Comment: 2. isn't correct either, if the method is defined in a header it must be marked `inline` otherwise you'll get duplicate definition errors, `inline` doesn't control compiler inlining

Comment: Probably with the second snippet you could even make this more useful by returning creating a function with return type `std::osyncstream` which would allow for usage of all `<<` operators instead of just the one for `std::string`...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh, correct. I had to double-check the standard. It's just synchronized in practice because no one locks and unlocks a mutex for every single character.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'll fix the wording

Comment: @fabian in that case the function wouldn't be required to begin with. You can simply write `std::osyncstream(std::cout) << string << '\n'`

Comment: Compilers not inlining isn't true either: https://godbolt.org/z/zxcT1WG4b

Comment: @AlanBirtles Huh, thanks for the heads-up. That's very different from my previous tests.

Comment: @Homer512 Introducing such a function often is a useful point to possibly adjust the functionality later. Maybe you later decide to write to `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` or you want to add a prefix containing the time; with your suggested code you'd need to adjust every single place `std::osyncstream(std::cout)` is used, with a function; you just need to rewrite that function...

Comment: not sure what the standard says exactly, but actually I question OPs approach to only pass strings and once you want to `std::cout << some_object << other_object;` the `<<` overload can do anything, and synchronization should be for the whole expression rather than for individual `<<`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm working under the assumption that this is simplified and their helpers may include more options, if required. However, having just a single print-string function isn't always bad, either. Seeing how formatted output, e.g. of doubles, is pretty CPU-intense, having multiple threads format their output into `ostringstreams` and then transfer those with a short locked operation to stdout or a file stream can improve performance, depending on the context.

Comment: I use this functionality where users of the library also may print something to std::cout using functions from the library. That may be something simple as giving an overview of the options of a print-format class, but also printing a complete matrix to std::cout. For those functions I like to have this thread safe, plus whatever may be needed later on. Better fix this now than refactor a lot later on.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the lock. `std::unique_lock` is a RAI type. All it does is acquire a lock on the mutex when constructed and release it when destroyed. Your lock is never destroyed because it is static. Well, it is destroyed at the end of the program, but that makes the use of `std::unique_lock` moot to begin with.

If you want to manually lock and unlock, you do not need `std::unique_lock`:

```
inline void HelperFunctions::controlStdCoutAccess(const StdCoutAccess mode)
{
    static std::mutex m;
    if (mode == StdCoutAccess::Lock)
        m.lock();
    else
        m.unlock();
}
```

However, now the usage is not exception safe anymore. For example:

```
controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Lock);
std::cout << string;
some_function_that_might_throw();
controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Unlock);
```

If `some_function_that_might_throw()` throws an exception the mutex is never unlocked. You can use a RAII wrapper to avoid that issue, but rather than `std::unique_lock` use one that locks the global mutex:

```
 struct My_Locker { 
      static std::mutex mut;
      My_Locker() { mut.lock(); }
      ~My_Locker() { mut.unlock(); }
      My_Locker(My_Locker&&) = delete; 
      MyLocker& operator=(My_Locker&&) = delete;
 };
 std::mutex My_Locker::mut;
```

And then

```
{
    My_Locker lock;
    std::cout << string;
    some_function_that_might_throw();  // when this throws the mutex is released
}                                      // if not it is release here
```

Or simply

```
{
    std::unique_lock lck(global_mutex);
    std::cout << string;
    some_function_that_might_throw();  // when this throws the mutex is released
}                                      // if not it is release here
```

But that requires a global `global_mutex` that I would rather wrap somehow like above.

Comment: @fabian absolutely. thx

Comment: Note that the initialisation order of `mut` in `My_Locker` isn't guaranteed

Comment: @AlanBirtles: could you explain for me? Would an inline static be different?

Comment: @AlanBirtles not sure what you mean. It is an issue when the mutex is used inside some other static initialization, but then the issue is already with that intialization and initialization of `std::cout`, no?

Comment: In a small test I see that this does not seem to work. In this code My_Locker(); results in a temporary object that is destructed directly, so the lock is released also immediately and std::cout is not protected anymore.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma oh sorry my fault. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to automatically release the mutex at the end of the function for some reason then simply don't use a `std::unique_lock`, using a `static` one is fairly pointless:

```
// Mutexed access to std::out.
inline void HelperFunctions::controlStdCoutAccess(const StdCoutAccess mode)
{
    static std::mutex m;

    // Check if we lock or unlock.
    if (mode == StdCoutAccess::Lock)
        m.lock();
    else
        m.unlock();
}

// Print to std::cout, but mutexed for thread safety.
inline void HelperFunctions::mutexedPrint(const std::string& string)
{
    controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Lock);
    std::cout << string;
    controlStdCoutAccess(StdCoutAccess::Unlock);
}
```

You'd be much better off using a local lock to access the mutex though, you can even create the lock in your `control` function:

```
// Mutexed access to std::out.
inline std::unique_lock<std::mutex> HelperFunctions::controlStdCoutAccess()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{m};
}

// Print to std::cout, but mutexed for thread safety.
inline void HelperFunctions::mutexedPrint(const std::string& string)
{
    auto lock = controlStdCoutAccess();
    std::cout << string;
}
```

Your approach has a number of issues:

1. You need to remember to call unlock exactly once for each call to lock. Calling `lock` when you've already locked the mutex has undefined behaviour. The same applies to calling `unlock` when you haven't locked the mutex. `std::unique_lock` does at least turn these scenarios into exceptions rather than undefined behaviour.
2. If any of your code throws exceptions the mutex could remain locked unintentionally and your program will then stop working correctly.